# Binding a Combobox inside a ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a combobox in a ListView that I can bind to an itemsource. When selecting a value in the combobox, my selected item is not getting set. Can someone show me why my selected item (NumberOfIterations) is not getting set? The combobox works when I move it outside the ListView, making me thinkg that I do not have the binding completely correct, but I cannot figure out what is wrong. I use the SimpleMVVMToolkit framework.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SequenceListItems}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SequenceListItemSelected}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}" 
    AlternationCount="2">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="# of Iterations" Width="125">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding
SequenceEditorViewModel.Iterations, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=NumberOfIterations, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" 
FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="60" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel Items...I am not using a Model at this time

```
// Constructor
public SequenceEditorViewModel()
{
    // Populate the Iterations for displaying in the combobox in the gridview.
    for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x++)
    {
        this.Iterations.Add(x);
    }
}

//public property (Iterations is source for combobox and NumberOfIterations 
//is for the selected item in the combobox)
public ObservableCollection<int> Iterations
{
    get
    {
        return this.iterations;
    }

    set
    {
        this.iterations = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.Iterations);
    }
}

public int NumberOfIterations
{
    get
    {
        return this.numberOfIterations;
    }

    set
    {
        this.numberOfIterations = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.NumberOfIterations);
    }
}
```

Comment: assuming NumberOfIterations defined in your viewmodel, The context for each element in the list (i.e. each combobox) is a single element of the 'SequenceListItems' enumerable.  In order to reference your viewmodel you will need to specify a source similar to the way you specify it in the combobox itemsource... Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}.

Comment: I tried changing the selected item to: SelectedItem="{Binding SequenceEditorViewModel.NumberOfIterations, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}" but did not have any success. The binding does work part of the way. I can set a breakpoint on NumberOfIterations get and it gets hit. When I select an item, the set does not get hit.

Comment: Hi there, I have my ComboBox placed inside a ContentControl and it seems to work fine . I.e. <StackPanel><ContentControl><ComboBox>. HTH

Comment: Thanks, but my combobox works if I move it out of my ListView/GridView Container. I'm sure it is something in my binding on my ListView that cannot cause the binding to work properly but I cannot figure it out.